# Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$general_settings

Tags: php, codeigniter, admin

Framework: codeigniter

Actually am facing some issue. I created an admin panel where I can change the logo of the site and it works in the panel but if I load the logo on the website index page but if I load logo in website index page then it will returns this error.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$general_settings

Filename: views/index.php

Line Number: 6

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hrdk\application\views\index.php
Line: 6
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hrdk\application\controllers\Home.php
Line: 8
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hrdk\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

http://localhost/hrdk/" alt="Logo" >

**Website index page code is here**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<img src="<?= base_url($this->general_settings['logo']); ?>" alt="Logo" >

</body>
</html>
```

**website index page controler code is here**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('index');
}
}
```

Comment: *" but if I load the logo on the website index page but if I load logo in website index page then it will returns this error"* ... this is unclear, could you please explain better, thanks

Comment: I have an admin panel where I can update my website logo, okay, and it's working in the admin panel header logo but if I try to add this logo to the website home page then it will return this error.  Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$general_settings

Comment: $general_settings comes from the config.php, right? how does that look like?, please update your question, don't place as comment

Comment: Can you show me your general_settings() function where you define ???